# How to prevent sleep on Ubuntu 20.04 Live

Tags: 20.04, live-usb, power-management

I'm using a Ubuntu 20.04 Live USB to run some gparted and backup work across my drives, but it keeps going to sleep after a while, stopping the backup process.

The settings menu crashes when I try to open it so I can't access the power settings to turn off sleep. How do I stop it from going to sleep?

Things i've tried:

- Try Gparted Live .iso instead - does not work on my new hardware
- ```
  sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
  ```
- Opening the 'Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS' installer and leaving it open - didn't work

for some reason putting a heavy object on the keyboard typing stuff to a terminal didn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Caffeine from the software center worked

Answer (score 7):

If you can install dconf-editor (via Ubuntu Software or via command line) then you should be able to use that GUI tool to edit the relevant setting.

Use dconf-editor to search for `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`

And I think you would need to change `sleep-inactive-ac-type` and/or `sleep-inactive-battery-type` from the default `suspend` to `nothing`

More info about the tool here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DconfEditor

Comment: managed to toggle those settings with gsettings, but it still goes to sleep after a while
i'll try setting the battery variables too